# How to initialise WP_Query on the basis of a specific meta_value and continue iterating rest?

Tags: php, custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, array

I have a CPT with daily deals, I need to show these daily deals on my frontend as per today's day.

For eg, if it is Thursday : The returning array should return Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday.

For this to happen I have a **meta_value** on all posts namely Day which returns days in the following order:

```
$days = [
  1 => 'Monday',
  2 => 'Tuesday',
  3 => 'Wednesday',
  4 => 'Thursday',
  5 => 'Friday',
  6 => 'Saturday',
  7 => 'Sunday',
];
```

My current WP_Query is follows which returns data in ascending order according to date : Monday to Sunday

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'special',
    'meta_key' => 'day',
    'orderby' => 'day',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
```

I want to construct a query such as I can assign a starting day and then continue the rest of the days.

Could anyone please help?

I tried adding comparing operators but they just remove the rest of the days as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a pure PHP and array question so I believe I can help.

You may wish to make friends with these to PHP functions:

- [array_push()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) - Push one or more elements onto the end of array
- [array_shift()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) - Shift an element off the beginning of array

There are more efficient ways to reorder an array, but this will work.

```
array_push($days,array_shift($days));
```

This should pull the first item from the array and put it on the end of the array. This is not necessarily the most efficient way but an array of 7 items probably does not matter too much.

**Also: FYI**, I've not tested this code but I am pretty confident it will cycle an array by one. You are still going to want logic for how many cycles to us (probably doing nothing on 7).